# Linq Where not filtering values

Tags: c#, linq

I am struggling with a supposedly easy LINQ where clause. 
Here my example:

```
Dictionary<string,string> test= new Dictionary<string,string>();

test.Add("12342","F650");
test.Add("12341","F000");
test.Add("12340","F650");
test.Add("12343","0E0E");

var result=test;

string searchCriteria = "F000,0E0E";

foreach (string tsearchCritera in searchCriteria.Split(','))
{
    string temp = tsearchCritera;
    result.Where(a=>a.Value.Equals(temp));
}

result.Select(a=>a.Key).Dump();
```

I expected to get the result:

```
12341 and 12343
```

Instead it returns all entries of the Dictionary.

Any idea how to solve this to get only the two matching entries?

Comment: `result = result.Where(a=>a.Value.Equals(temp));`

Comment: `result.Where(a=>a.Value.Equals(temp));` you aren't doing anything with the return of this.

Comment: Linq is functionally designed: Everything returns a value instead of manipulating the source. This style of coding is less error-prone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.Where()` does not act as an in-place, in-collection filter; it only applies a filter to the collection with the expectation that you then resolve the query downstream when you enumerate the collection (such as with `.Select()` or `.ToList()`), applying the filter ***during*** the resolution of the query.

You need to return the result of `.Where()` and use that new result to select the matched keys.

```
Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>();

test.Add("12342", "F650");
test.Add("12341", "F000");
test.Add("12340", "F650");
test.Add("12343", "0E0E");

var result = test;
var filteredResults = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

string searchCriteria = "F000,0E0E";

foreach (string tsearchCritera in searchCriteria.Split(','))
{
    string temp = tsearchCritera;
    filteredResults.AddRange(result.Where(a => a.Value.Equals(temp)));
}

filteredResults.Select(a => a.Key).Dump();
```

Comment: .Select() doesn't enumerate the collection. The actual execution of the query is deferred until you iterate over the query variable in a foreach statement. To force immediate execution of any query and cache its results, you can call the ToList or ToArray methods. Queries that perform aggregation functions over a range (Count, Max, Average, and First ) don't require explicit foreach.  Details about it are in - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries